# More Rows vs More Tables

Tags: database, database-design

I have recently started designing database for one of my project. I am confused on one simple question "More Rows vs More Tables". I am not experienced enough to answer this question. Any help on this will be appreciated. Here is the scenario:

**Scenario**

I Have a Company. Company will have many Users, Vehicles.

More Rows:
Should I have 1 table for user and vehicle with reference to COMPANY_ID. Obviously over time it will have a lot of records. I have to use GUID as ID because of the requirement. So if it has too many records, I think it will effect the searching operation as well.

More Tables:
Should I have 2 tables created every time I add a new company with company prefix e.g. I add a new company "Tesla", table names will be like TESLA_USER, TESLA_VEHICLES. Obviously over time number of tables will increase a lot.

My concern is which is more efficient way? More Rows or More Tables?

Thank you

Cheers
D

Comment: To use your terms, you want "more rows".  Stephane Rothen's answer includes a good example of how to lay it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a table for the Companies, a table for users and a table for vehicles in which you put all your data. Then you add two joining tables who only stores the links between companies and users and companies and vehicles.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbDpU.png)